# getting garbage data from external dataflash on STK600

Tags: embedded, spi, eeprom

Hello,
         I am using STK600 and I have written code for external dataflash using SPI. When I read data from dataflash I receive first data byte properly but then afterwards I receive all data bytes as garbage values. The data which I am reading in SPI interrupt, putting same data on UART in PWM interrupt. Both SPI and PWM interupts are working properly.
         I have also tried by putting data byte value on LED port in SPI interrupt to confirm if there is any data corruption before it goes to UART in PWM interrupt. But I found that both data values(one on LED port and other on hyperterminal) are both same so no data corruption.
         I am directly receiving garbage values from SPI interrupt itself. Please help me, here are my code files.

```
      #include <asf.h>


      //Slave select low

      #define cs_low() \
      delay_us(10);\
      PORTB=(0<<PB0);\
      delay_us(10);

      //Slave select high

      #define cs_high() \
      delay_us(10);\
      PORTB=(1<<PB0);\
      delay_us(10);


      char opcode_cnt=0;               //Counts number bytes required before start reading actual data
      unsigned char data;         //Array to save save received data
      unsigned int dummy_byte_cnt=0;            //total dummy bytes sent to receive data
      volatile char rd_cmplete_flg=0;   //Flag is set after read operation completed
      int pg_addr;                     //Indicates address of page
      int buff_addr;                   //Indicates starting address of buffer
      unsigned int i=0;
      int array[3];
      char sample_count=4,pwm_init=0;


      void init_pwm(void);
      void spimstr_init(void);
      void spi_tx(unsigned char byte);
      void spi_tx_ISR(unsigned char byte);
      unsigned char spi_rx_ISR(void);
      unsigned char spi_rx(void);
      unsigned char get_status(void);
      void init_uart(void);
      void pg_erase(unsigned int pg_addr);
      void continuous_pg_read(unsigned int page_address,unsigned int buffer_address);




      int main (void)
    {
      // Insert system clock initialization code here (sysclk_init()).

      board_init();

      init_uart();

      spimstr_init();

      continuous_pg_read(0x00,0x00);

      while(1)
    {
       if(rd_cmplete_flg)

          init_pwm();            
    }

     // Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized.
   }



    void spimstr_init()
   {
    //Master Mode Selected
    //MSB out first
    //Clock Polarity and Clock Phase selected as 1
    //Clock Frequency 8MHz/2 selected

    SPCR|=(1<<SPE)|(0<<DORD)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<CPOL)|(1<<CPHA)|(0<<SPR1)|  (0<<SPR0);

    SPSR=(1<<SPI2X);             //Doubles the clock frequency
   }



    void spi_tx(unsigned char byte)
   {
    SPDR=byte;

    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF)));        //wait until transmission is completed
   }



    void spi_tx_ISR(unsigned char byte)
   {
    SPDR=byte;
   }


    unsigned char spi_rx()
   {
    spi_tx(0x00);                    //sending dummy byte

    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF)));        //wait until reception is completed

    return SPDR;
   }


    unsigned char spi_rx_ISR()
   {
    return SPDR;
   }




     unsigned char get_status()
   {
     unsigned char status;

     //high to low transition made on SS

     cs_low();

     spi_tx(0xd7);            //opcode to read status register of EEPROM

     status=spi_rx();         //Received the value of status register of EEPROM

     status=status & 0x80;

     //low to high transition made on SS

     cs_high();

     return status;
    }


     void pg_erase(unsigned int pg_addr)
    {
     while(get_status()==0x00);

     cs_low();

     spi_tx(0x81);

     spi_tx((0x00)|(pg_addr>>7));

     spi_tx((pg_addr<<1)|0x00);

     spi_tx(0x00);

     cs_high();
    }


     void init_uart()
    {
     UBRR1H=0x00;

     UBRR1L=0x01;          //Baud rate 256000 selected      

     UCSR1B|=(1<<RXEN1)|(1<<TXEN1);

     UCSR1C|=(1<<UCSZ11)|(1<<UCSZ10);
    }



     void continuous_pg_read(unsigned int page_address,unsigned int buffer_address)
    {
     pg_addr=page_address;

     buff_addr=buffer_address;

     while(get_status()==0x00);

     cs_low();

     spi_tx(0xe8);                           //opcode to read page

     SREG=0x80;

     SPCR|=(1<<SPIE);
   }



     void init_pwm()
   {
      if(!pwm_init)
     {
      pwm_init=1;

      DDRB = (1<<PB5);                          // set OC1A as output

      TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A1)|(1<<COM1A0)|(1<<WGM10);// set OC1A on compare match,clear OC1A at bottom
      // 8 bit fast PWM

      TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS10);               // 8bit fast PWM and clock=8Mhz   
     }

      TIMSK1|=(1<<TOIE1);                     // enable timer 1 overflow interrupt
    }





      ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
    {
      //PORTA=0x55;

      //delay_ms(15000);

      sample_count--;

      if(sample_count==0)
     {
        sample_count=4;

        if(rd_cmplete_flg)
       {
          TIMSK1=(0<<TOIE1);

          rd_cmplete_flg=0;

          UDR1=data;

          while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<UDRE1)));

           i++;

           if(i>=23923)
          {
           SREG=0x00;
          }

           cs_low();

           spi_tx_ISR(0xe8);
         }
       } 
        //PORTA=~PORTA;

        //delay_ms(15000);
      }





      //ISR for Continuous Array Read mode

        ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
   {
         //PORTA=0xff;

         //delay_ms(15000);

         opcode_cnt++;

         switch(opcode_cnt)
       {
         case 1:

              //PORTA=0X11;

              //delay_ms(15000);

              spi_tx_ISR((0x00)|(pg_addr>>7));

              break;

         case 2:

             //PORTA=0X22;

             //delay_ms(15000);

             spi_tx_ISR((pg_addr<<1)|(buff_addr>>8));

             break;

         case 3:

            //PORTA=0X33;

            //delay_ms(15000);

            spi_tx_ISR(buff_addr & 0x00ff);

            break;

         case 4:

            //PORTA=0X44;

            //delay_ms(15000);

             spi_tx_ISR(0x00);

             break;

         case 5:

            //PORTA=0X55;

            //delay_ms(15000);

            spi_tx_ISR(0x00);

            break;

        case 6:

            //PORTA=0X66;

            //delay_ms(15000);

            spi_tx_ISR(0x00);

            break;

        case 7:

            //PORTA=0X77;

            //delay_ms(15000);

            spi_tx_ISR(0x00);

            break;

        case 8:

            spi_tx_ISR(0x00);

            break;  
       }


           if(opcode_cnt>=9)
        {
            opcode_cnt=0;                //Reset to zero to repeat switch case

            if(rd_cmplete_flg==0)
           {
             data=spi_rx_ISR();

             //PORTA=data;

             //delay_ms(15000);     

             rd_cmplete_flg=1;
            }
             //Important Note

             //The buffer address and page address has to be incremented before cs_high() only then only this mode works

             if(buff_addr<263)
            {
             buff_addr++;
            }

             else
            {
             buff_addr=0;

             pg_addr++;
            }

           cs_high();

           //PORTA=0x30;

           dummy_byte_cnt++;

           //PORTA=0x40;

           //cs_low();

           //spi_tx_ISR(0xe8);            //Resend page read opcode to    read next  byte of data

            if(dummy_byte_cnt>=23923)
           {
            SREG=0x00;

            buff_addr=0;

            pg_addr=0;

            dummy_byte_cnt=0;
           }
         }
        //PORTA=~PORTA;

        //delay_ms(15000);
       }



        void board_init(void)
       {
        DDRA|=0xff;                          //optput port for LED

        DDRB|=(1<<DDB2)|(1<<DDB1)|(1<<DDB0);     //Direction of SS,MISO,SCK,MOSI  pin selected
       }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a hex comparison of the expected vs. received values.  Perhaps you could take a step back and temporarily try a non-interrupt busy-wait SPI access and see if you get the right data then.  Also try a slower clock, and make sure you have decoupling caps.  Will the part let you read the status register multiple times in the same access?  That could be a good test too.  A scope or cheap logic analyzer can be good for verifying what is actually happening on the wire is what you think should be or imagine from the received data.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially problematic:

> > unsigned char data;         //Array to save save received data

First, that is not an array, but rather storage for a single character, however you don't appear to be trying to store an array there, so it is merely misdecribed.

However, you *do* appear to be accessing this from both the ISR and the main thread, and if you are going to do that you need to declare it as volatile.  Otherwise, the compiler is free to cache the value in a register which could make it private to a given thread, or even worse, decide that no one ever uses the value and so decline to store it at all.

You have protected your flag that way, but you need to protect the data as well.

Comment: Actually "data" is variable which I used it as array initially and forgot to remove from comment. Even if I am using it in both PWM and SPI ISR do I need to declare it as volatile?

Comment: It is working properly by polling method and reading status register was also in my mind but it is little bit difficult, it needs to send an opcode and few bytes further.

Comment: Hardware is fine and also tried by varrying SPI and PWM frequency, one doubt in my mind is do I need to check status register every time even if I use interrupt.

Comment: What the consequences of neglecting to declare it as volatile are will vary by compiler and phase of the moon, but in principle, yes, you must do that for anything which you access from both an interrupt and the main thread of program flow - which you do for that variable.

Comment: Chris you are right I changed my logic in order to read status register, I am getting ready status for first time only then further it gives me busy status, what should I do in that case???? Need your help desperately.

Comment: Rather I get value of status register as 0x00